# Blocking/Synchronous function call in AIDL

Tags: android

I am working on a android service, this service provided a AIDL interface for applications, Now application calls function GetData() using AIDL interface, this function is implemented in Service , it does some network operation, connect to server and fetch some data, this network transaction happen in background thread, Problem is that I want function GetData() should NOT return until network operation is complete, result comes from server and I want to return it into GetData(), GetData function returns immediately and network operation in background thread keep on running in parallel, how to avoid this, cannot call network operation also in main thread. I read about countDownlatch, is it only possible solution?

```
                        Service Main Thread

                            GetData
                                 GetDataFromServer-----------> in Background thread
      /*this is problem */  GetData returns;                         |
                                                                     |
                                                                     |
                                                              communication in progress
                                                                     |
                                                                     |
                                                                     |
      /*I want GetData should return here <-------------------transaction complete
```

Answer (score 2):

Create some interface and implement that interface in your class  and pass the interface object to that particular service after response came from the network pass the data to that interface object.

i think this help you.

Comment: I think this is not blocking in nature, I need Blocking/Synchronous behaviour

Answer (score 0):

you can call startService from AsyncTask.I can have the same problem in my nearest place application that need data from google map.`enter code here`

```
protected void getLocationAndUpdatePlaces(boolean updateWhenLocationChanges) {
// This isn't directly affecting the UI, so put it on a worker thread.
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> findLastLocationTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Find the last known location, specifying a required accuracy of within the min distance between updates
    // and a required latency of the minimum time required between updates.

  // start a service that require data from web.

  }
};
findLastLocationTask.execute();
```

`